# Unable to open the Chrome browser in android emulator by manually

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, appium

I have successfully installed chrome apk file in emulator, but facing problem when I tried to open it by manually, and observed following error traces in log file. And the browser is automatically killed.

```
D/dalvikvm( 2246): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome-1/libchrome
.1916.122.so 0x40cebcb0
I/LibraryLoader( 2246): Time to load native libraries: 268 ms (timestamps 3761-4
029)
I/LibraryLoader( 2246): Expected native library version number "35.0.1916.122",a
ctual native library version number "35.0.1916.122"
I/chromium( 2246): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled:
 level = 0, default verbosity = 0
D/dalvikvm( 2246): GREF has increased to 201
E/SurfaceFlinger(   36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
I/Choreographer( 2246): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
D/gralloc_goldfish( 2246): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/ActivityManager(  280): Start proc com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0 for s
ervice com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0: pid
=2268 uid=99006 gids={}
E/Trace   ( 2268): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/ActivityManager(  280): Displayed com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.c
hrome.Main: +4s416ms
I/Choreographer( 2246): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
I/ChildProcessService( 2268): Creating new ChildProcessService pid=2268
I/LibraryLoader( 2268): Loading: chrome.1916.122
D/dalvikvm( 2268): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome-1/libchro
me.1916.122.so 0x40ce9818
I/BrowserStartupController( 2246): Initializing chromium process, renderers=9
D/dalvikvm( 2268): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome-1/libchrome
.1916.122.so 0x40ce9818
I/LibraryLoader( 2268): Time to load native libraries: 862 ms (timestamps 5636-6
498)
I/LibraryLoader( 2268): Expected native library version number "35.0.1916.122",a
ctual native library version number "35.0.1916.122"
D/dalvikvm( 2246): GREF has increased to 301
I/Choreographer( 2246): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too mu
ch work on its main thread.
E/dalvikvm( 2246): Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager', re
ferenced from method org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid.hasBluetoothHeadset
W/dalvikvm( 2246): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 66 (Landroid/bluetooth/Blue
toothManager;) in Lorg/chromium/media/AudioManagerAndroid;
D/dalvikvm( 2246): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x001f
I/Choreographer( 2246): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too muc
h work on its main thread.
D/libEGL  ( 2246): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software r
enderer.
D/libEGL  ( 2246): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
E/chromium( 2246): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(109)] No suitable EGL configs found.

E/chromium( 2246): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOne
Off failed.
F/chromium( 2246): [FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(951)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff
 failed
W/google-breakpad( 2246): Output crash dump file:
W/google-breakpad( 2246): /data/data/com.android.chrome/cache/Crash Reports/46cc
e176-e05f-f087-5023df93-01906ce1.dmp
W/google-breakpad( 2246): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad( 2246): Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad( 2246): 35.0.1916.122
W/google-breakpad( 2246): 1916122
W/google-breakpad( 2246): 9cc8db74-d0a6-4a6f-9bf9-352164051a64
W/google-breakpad( 2246): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
F/libc    ( 2246): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000008c6 (code=-6), thread 224
6 (.android.chrome)
I/DEBUG   (   34): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *
**
I/DEBUG   (   34): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.2.2/JB_MR1.1/576024
:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   34): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (   34): pid: 2246, tid: 2246, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.android.chrome <
<<
I/DEBUG   (   34): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaa
d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 4006b258  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r4 00000000  r5 be8cbdf4  r6 be8cc3e4  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     r8 4006b228  r9 43e90e14  sl 00000000  fp be8cc694
I/DEBUG   (   34):     ip 4c1a6b00  sp be8cbdf0  lr 4003e2c9  pc 4003a962  cpsr
60000030
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d0  4403800043e70000  d1  c248000042f60000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d2  42920000448dc000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d4  0000000000000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d6  0000000000000000  d7  448dc00042920000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d8  0000000040c00000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     scr 20000011
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #00  pc 0001a962  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #01  pc 00018048  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #02  pc 00393cf1  /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome-1/libc
hrome.1916.122.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): stack:
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdb0  400681b4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdb4  00000045
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdb8  400681b4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdbc  be8cbdfc  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdc0  400681b4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdc4  be8cbdfc  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdc8  40068254  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdcc  400681b4  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdd0  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdd4  4003e2c9  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdd8  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbddc  be8cbdf4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbde0  be8cc3e4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbde4  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbde8  df0027ad
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdec  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #00  be8cbdf0  be8cbe94  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdf4  fffffbdf
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdf8  00c12bea
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbdfc  4006b228
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe00  43e90e14
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe04  93e54ce6
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe08  be8cc694  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe0c  be8cbe34  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe10  be8cc3e8  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe14  4003804c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_c
lone)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #01  be8cbe18  93e54ce6
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe1c  4a6a0cf5  /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome
-1/libchrome.1916.122.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):     #02  be8cbe20  00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe24  4b5b1e05  /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome
-1/libchrome.1916.122.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe28  be8cbe74  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe2c  00000002
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe30  be8cbf24  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe34  2a1999e8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe38  be8cbf68  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe3c  00001008
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe40  2a186320  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe44  2a1999e5  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe48  2a1999a0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe4c  4b59f8e3  /data/app-lib/com.android.chrome
-1/libchrome.1916.122.so
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe50  00000002
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe54  be8cc04c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe58  00000001
I/DEBUG   (   34):          be8cbe5c  00001008
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b258 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b298 00000000 00000000 00433c4e 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b308 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b318 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b328 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbdd4 4003e2c9 00000001 be8cbdf4 be8cc3e4
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbde4 00000000 df0027ad 00000000 be8cbe94
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbdf4 fffffbdf 00c12bea 4006b228 43e90e14
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe04 93e54ce6 be8cc694 be8cbe34 be8cc3e8
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe14 4003804c 93e54ce6 4a6a0cf5 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe24 4b5b1e05 be8cbe74 00000002 be8cbf24
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe34 2a1999e8 be8cbf68 00001008 2a186320
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe44 2a1999e5 2a1999a0 4b59f8e3 00000002
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe54 be8cc04c 00000001 00001008 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe64 00000020 0000002b 0000002d be8cbfa0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe74 4c1f5ae8 0000a000 4b5abe90 00000002
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe84 00000000 be8cbe78 be8cbe78 0000000a
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe94 5441465b 623a4c41 73776f72 6d5f7265
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbea4 5f6e6961 706f6f6c 2863632e 29313539
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbeb4 4c47205d 66727553 3a656361 696e493a
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbec4 6c616974 4f657a69 664f656e 61662066
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc3c4 0000002f 2a252488 4b5a48b7 be8cc480
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc3d4 be8cc45c 2a24c918 4b5ca53b 2a16b26c
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc3e4 00000004 4c0b0244 4c0a98a8 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc3f4 00000000 00000000 2a199958 2a19999d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc404 2a19999d 4c1f5ae8 00000010 2a1999a0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc414 003a4c41 00000001 4b5c6cdb 2a19999d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc424 2a199958 4c0b0258 00001008 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc434 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000006
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc444 00000000 4c1f5ae8 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc454 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc464 00000000 2a1ab5d0 00000020 be8cc3ec
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc474 00000000 00000022 4bb13b3b 000003b7
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc484 93e54ce6 00000000 2a1970b8 2a1b7520
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc494 4c1c48f4 4c1c4ae4 77200019 43e90e14
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc4a4 00000000 be8cc694 4b5cc085 4b5ecb3d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc4b4 00000000 2a1b2b10 4b5cbfc3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b208 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b218 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b228 93e54ce6 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b238 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b248 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b258 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b268 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b278 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b288 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b298 00000000 00000000 00433c4e 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4006b2f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00004000
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near r9:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90df4 00000000 00000000 43e90e38 49df38e6
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e04 441aa850 00000006 00000000 77200019
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e14 2a1b7520 00000000 f34ee7b1 00000001
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e24 43e90e64 456774c4 441aa938 49df38e6
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e34 00000000 2a1b7520 00000000 f34ee7b1
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e44 00000001 40ed57c8 40d3aa60 43e90e84
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e54 45860798 43f6cf18 456774c4 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e64 00000000 40ed57c8 40d3aa60 43e90ec4
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e74 4569b6f4 44017688 45860798 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e84 000008c6 0000273f 00000000 40ce4a08
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90e94 40d3aa60 000008c6 0000273f 40ce4a28
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90ea4 40ed57c8 00000000 40ce9af8 43e90eec
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90eb4 00000000 43f2f860 4569b6f4 00000012
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90ec4 40ce4a98 40ce4ba0 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90ed4 40ce3f78 43e90f00 00000000 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     43e90ee4 00000000 459db7b0 43e90f34 44f42802
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc674 4074e294 f34ee7b1 00000001 43e90e10
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc684 00000001 40ed57c8 00000000 40d2c470
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc694 4077d1fd 43e90e10 49eadcde 4b5cbec5
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6a4 2a00bbb8 00000000 00000000 c0000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6b4 4006b228 00000000 00000000 2a13b358
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6c4 4003139b 00000000 00000000 45abbd24
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6d4 00000000 00000008 2a00bba8 ffffbfff
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6e4 00000001 2a00bbd0 407a23cf 2a00bba8
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc6f4 2a00bba8 00000000 2a13b350 00000008
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc704 407a7f13 00000048 00001000 00000003
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc714 00000004 00000000 40cd6008 00000013
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc724 00000003 00000002 00000001 00000004
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc734 00000005 00000033 00000001 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc744 407e00b8 00000000 43ef5858 45abbd24
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc754 00000000 45ad69c5 4074e400 00000006
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cc764 43e90a84 0000000a 00000001 2a009ab0
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6ae0 40041841 40041951 40038904 40039750
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6af0 400385d8 40039880 40032749 4003817c
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b00 40038044 4003e8a9 400841f8 40088550
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b10 4002cf09 4002cef5 4003ade5 4003e775
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b20 40036e5c 40080a28 400457e5 400824c0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b30 4007c068 4003d941 4003d125 40038b9c
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b40 40086340 40083e50 400805f0 400807f0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b50 4003d7a5 40083cf8 40044fad 4003ed1d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b60 40058ccb 400458f9 40041b3d 40080708
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b70 4003d825 4003d301 4002d520 4002dfc8
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b80 4003ec6d 4002d72c 40038e99 4002dc54
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6b90 40037bf4 4004148d 40036d44 4002eec1
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6ba0 40036d60 40036e00 40037078 4003ae5d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6bb0 400379ec 4004a91d 400370d0 40037b10
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6bc0 40047ffd 40047f7f 40045231 40045317
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4c1a6bd0 400374c0 4003bf83 400368a8 40042ec9
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbdd0 00000000 4003e2c9 00000001 be8cbdf4
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbde0 be8cc3e4 00000000 df0027ad 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbdf0 be8cbe94 fffffbdf 00c12bea 4006b228
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe00 43e90e14 93e54ce6 be8cc694 be8cbe34
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe10 be8cc3e8 4003804c 93e54ce6 4a6a0cf5
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe20 00000000 4b5b1e05 be8cbe74 00000002
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe30 be8cbf24 2a1999e8 be8cbf68 00001008
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe40 2a186320 2a1999e5 2a1999a0 4b59f8e3
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe50 00000002 be8cc04c 00000001 00001008
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe60 00000000 00000020 0000002b 0000002d
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe70 be8cbfa0 4c1f5ae8 0000a000 4b5abe90
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe80 00000002 00000000 be8cbe78 be8cbe78
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbe90 0000000a 5441465b 623a4c41 73776f72
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbea0 6d5f7265 5f6e6961 706f6f6c 2863632e
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbeb0 29313539 4c47205d 66727553 3a656361
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8cbec0 696e493a 6c616974 4f657a69 664f656e
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a940 e000b164 6823461c d1fb2b00 68e3e026
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a950 4a17b123 447a2401 47986014 20274911
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a960 70082400 ea7af7fc f7fd2106 a902ebde
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a970 f04f2006 460a5380 94029304 f7fc9403
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a980 4629efc4 20024622 efccf7fc ea66f7fc
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a990 f7fd2106 2001ebca ef86f7fb 2a006962
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9a0 e7d4d1dc deadbaad 0002d636 0003091a
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9b0 000308fe 2400b510 aa04b088 46699002
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9c0 94014620 94039400 ef24f7fc bfb842a0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9d0 db054620 b1139b07 1c489906 98069006
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9e0 bd10b008 4604b510 e8baf7fc d10542a0
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003a9f0 447b4b04 6018681b bd102000 30fff04f
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003aa00 bf00bd10 0002d56a 460db538 481eb928
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003aa10 f7fc4478 2800ecb8 b9fdd130 2102481b
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003aa20 f0014478 2800faae db274604 f7fc4629
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003aa30 2800eb42 2101db0b f7fc4620 2800eb3c
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2a8 41f0e92d 4c0b2600 447c4680 68a56824
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2b8 e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2c8 35544306 d5f53f01 2c006824 4630d1ef
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2d8 81f0e8bd 00029cd2 43f0e92d fb01461f
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2e8 f8dff602 b0878058 44f8460c 8000f8d8
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e2f8 9001a901 f8d84615 20013000 96059602
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e308 90049103 4638b113 fa35f7ff a9034638
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e318 fe9bf7ff 2000f8d8 b1124681 f7ff4638
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e328 f1b9fa37 d0050f00 46219d05 f01a1b70
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e338 4605ecda b0074628 83f0e8bd 00029c4a
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e348 1e4b6841 2b006043 f000da01 6803bbab
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e358 2b01f813 46106003 00004770 4604b570
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e368 447e4e0d 68336836 f7ffb10b 6861fa04
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e378 60601e48 bfa22800 f8106820 60205b01
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e388 4620da03 fb8ef000 68324605 4620b112
I/DEBUG   (   34):     4003e398 f9fef7ff bd704628 00029bd2 447b4b07
I/DEBUG   (   34):
I/DEBUG   (   34): memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
I/DEBUG   (   34):     be8b8000-be8cd000 [stack]
I/DEBUG   (   34):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   (   34):     (no map above)
D/Zygote  (   37): Process 2246 terminated by signal (11)
I/ActivityManager(  280): Process com.android.chrome (pid 2246) has died.
I/WindowState(  280): WIN DEATH: Window{40eaf2c8 u0 SurfaceView}
I/ChildProcessService( 2268): Destroying ChildProcessService pid=2268
W/ActivityManager(  280): Force removing ActivityRecord{40d68280 u0 com.android.
chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main}: app died, no saved state
W/InputDispatcher(  280): channel '40dd0228 com.android.chrome/com.google.androi
d.apps.chrome.Main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurre
d.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  280): channel '40dd0228 com.android.chrome/com.google.androi
d.apps.chrome.Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be dispo
sed!
I/WindowState(  280): WIN DEATH: Window{40dd0228 u0 com.android.chrome/com.googl
e.android.apps.chrome.Main}
W/InputDispatcher(  280): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input cha
nnel '40dd0228 com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main (server)'
I/ActivityManager(  280): Isolated process com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0
 (pid 2268) no longer needed
E/SurfaceFlinger(   36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
W/ActivityManager(  280): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/InputMethodManagerService(  280): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false)
 notification to pid 2246 uid 10047
D/ExchangeService(  693): Received deviceId from Email app: null
D/ExchangeService(  693): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
```

Is anybody have experience with this issue? please help me out if you already faced and resolved the same.

I'm using windows 7 64 bit. android api level 17(4.2.2),and chrome 35apk.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://paul.kinlan.me/installing-chrome-for-android-on-an-emulator/)

Comment: It's really unfare to give negative flag guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of using snapshot option while creating AVD devices. I didn't check that box now. Which seems to be resolved this issue.